# Installing SSL certificate for a new domain using old domain's IP address

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6

On our Win-2003 server we used to have a single SSL certificate installed alongside multiple domains, e.g.

```
ssl.our-old.com    192.168.0.10
www.example.com    192.168.0.2
www.example.co.uk  192.168.0.2
```

I'm just showing the server's internal IPs. It's a public facing server with a firewall performing 1to1 NAT (if I got the term right).

We let the old SSL certificate expire when we no longer needed it.

I want to install a new SSL for a new domain on the server, re-using that IP address (192.168.0.10 in the example above).

Do I need to do anything other than just remove the old website in IIS Console? Or do I need to hunt out some other config before I can re-use this IP address on the new website, make the CSR etc?

```
ssl.example.co.uk  192.168.0.10 
www.example.com    192.168.0.2
www.example.co.uk  192.168.0.2
```

Comment: Assuming the SSL certificate was issued to a name (because AFAIK you can't issue an SSL certificate for a private ip address) then the ip address has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Is this web server accessible from within the company network only?

Comment: No, it's public facing. I'm just showing the server's actual IPs. There's a physical firewall in front that routes 2 external IPs to the 2 internal IPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public certificates are issued to domain names, not IP addresses.

If you want to create a new site with a new name, then yes, delete the old site and add the new one. The one thing you will want to look out for is to make sure that no one has the hostname/IP address pair hard coded in a hosts file or an application.